# UWP Application not building Release mode with .Net Native Tool Chain

Tags: build, uwp, msbuild, .net-native

I hope you're doing well,

I'm currently at a issue where my UWP application will not build/run in Release mode while "Compile with the .NET Native Tool Chain" option is enabled.

When building, I receive 244 errors such as the image:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmu4n.jpg)

I'm targeting 17134 for all Universal Windows projects in the solution. The application is referencing a few .Net Standard 2.0 libraries.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I'll work on creating that, Xavier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the minimal version of the application to target windows 16299, if anyone needs more detail, please ask. I'll see this eventually.